# Matrix multiplication algorithm over F_2 in just O(n^2.81/(log n)^0.4). Create algorithm. But how?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication, strassen

We have a matrix with elements in the field of integers modulo 2 (F_2). We are looking for algorithm that multiply n x n matrix over F_2 in just `O(n^2.81/(log n)^0.4)`

How it is possible?

I know, that Strassen's algorithm gives `O(n^2.81)`, but how can we get this factor of `(log n)^0.4`?

Comment: Do you have a reference saying that this is possible? A link to a paper would help.

Comment: You might want to look into the M4RI algorithm: http://m4ri.sagemath.org/ It doesn't achieve the running time you're looking for, but contains some worthwhile techniques.

Comment: No, it's my exercise for Algorithms and Data Structures. 
I get hint to use four russian algorithm and also decimal encoding for this logical matrix, but still don't know how we get `(log n^0.4)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do following:

Take each possible matrix with dimensions [image]. There are [image] such matrices ([image]).

Precompute multiplication result for these matrices. This gives you table with dimensions [image]. Then in recursion phase of Strassen algorithm, if required matrices for multiplication are small enough you can use precomputed values in this table (if smaller than [image] you could fill appropriate rows and cols with zeros). Let [image]. So you've got following recursion:

[image]

Notice, that the recurrence depth is [image], so you've got:

[image]

Using geometric series formula:

[image]